# GNU g++ -G option to create a shared library available on Solaris not on Linux

Tags: c, linux, g++, solaris, linker-flags

I am using GNU `g++ 4.9.2 compiler` both on `Solaris` and `Linux`.
On Solaris platform, to create a shared library from a source file (a.c), I use the following command:

```
g++ -G a.c -o a
```

`a` becomes a shared library
`a.c` contains the following code:

```
void libfn1()
{
}
```

If I try not to use -G option i.e. compile as:

```
g++ a.c -o a
```

It gets a linker error: `Undefined Symbol main`

But, on Linux, if I do the same thing: it says:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option -G
```

How to create a shared library on Linux? What is the `g++` option for that?

Comment: Have you tried *searching* for how to create shared libraries on Linux? There are plenty of examples and tutorials all over the Internet.

Comment: --shared should work.  You may also want -fPIC and --soname options.

Answer (score 1):

The g++ documentation says this:

> These additional options are available on System V Release 4 for
>   compatibility with other compilers on those systems:
>
> -G  Create a shared object.  It is recommended that -symbolic or -shared be 
>   used instead.

Normally you want to generate position independent code too, for a shared library, with the -fPIC flag.

So you'd want to run:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared a.c -o liba.so
```

Answer (score 1):

The process to create a shared library on a Linux system is a bit different.

Shared libraries on Linux are `.so` (for "shared object") files, not `.g`.

You do it like this:

First, you need to generate ***[position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)*** from your C++ source. That is so your library works from wherever it is called. To do that, you should use g++'s `-fPIC` flag.

So, for each source file you want to be included in your library, you should only compile it to position-independent code. We'll handle linking later.

For each source file:

`g++ -c -fPIC file.cpp`

(The `-c` flag tells g++ "compile, don't link").

for each `file.cpp`, g++ will generate `file.o`, an object file containing position-independent code.

To then build the object files into a shared library, you should use

`g++ -o -shared myLibrary.so {all_object_files}`

So if you have `file1.o`, `file2.o` and `file3.o`, the command would be:

`g++ -shared -o myLibrary.so file1.o file2.o file3.o`

Of course, if you have a lot of files this can get pretty tedious, so you should write a Makefile to automate this process for you! Here's an example:

```
myLibrary.so: file1.o file2.o file3.o
        $(CXX) -shared $^ -o $@ 

file1.o file2.o file3.o : CXXFLAGS+=-fPIC
```

Comment: Can -fPIC be used as compilation flag for non-shared objects too, I mean for executables?

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana The flag for executables is -fPIE, for "Position-Independent Executable". -fPIC is for libraries.